# Using the SQL LIKE operator with tuple insertion

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, pycharm

I am trying to write a SQL query where a user inputs a name, and with tuple insertion the query returns similar names in the database using the LIKE operator.

This is what I tried:

```
user_input = input('Enter name: ')
c.execute('SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Person WHERE FirstName LIKE('%' + ? + '%')', user_input)
```

```
user_input = input('Enter name: ')
c.execute('SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Person WHERE FirstName LIKE '%' + user_input + '%'')
```

```
user_input = input('Enter name: ')
c.execute('SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Person WHERE FirstName LIKE ?', '%' + user_input + '%')
```

However, the query fails to run and I am getting these errors.

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
TypeError: must be str, not tuple
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use double quotes to quote the SQL query in order to allow single quotes to quote the `%` characters:

```
c.execute("SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Person WHERE FirstName LIKE '%' || ? || '%'",
    (user_input,))
```

or pass to the placeholder in the SQL query a string with `user_input` already enclosed in `%` characters:

```
c.execute('SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Person WHERE FirstName LIKE ?',
    (f'%{user_input}%',))
```